# Foreach loop only returns value of first row

Tags: php

I have a large PDO statement that will return a max of 10 records. However, in my foreach loop, when I do a var dump, I see that only the data from the first record is returned. If there are 10 records, it shows only the same data from the first record 10 times. Ultimately, I am trying to grab the ID2 value for each row returned and store it in $blurb. But again, the way more foreach is currently written, the $ID2 will always be the value of the first record, no matter how many records are returned. Do I need something like $i=1 and break etc to get the var_dump results to show the different data for each row returned in the query?

```
//Query code ends here
$results2->execute();
$row2 = $results2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($row2 as $result5) {
echo var_dump($row2[0]);

}

$blurb = $row2[0]['ID2'];
```

Comment: `foreach ($row2 as $result5) {
   echo var_dump($result5);
}`

Comment: You are iterating as `$result5`. Use `var_dump($result5)`

Comment: (also, don't `echo var_dump()` -- the `echo` is superfluous since `var_dump()` writes to the output stream itself, and returns `null`, which is what gets sent to `echo`)

Comment: When i change to var_dump($results5) i just get null printed 10 times instead of the value of the first row printed 10 times. The only reason I am doing a var_dump is to see if each of the 10 rows returned are different values instead of row 1's value repeated over and over

Comment: Not `$results5`, rather `$result5`.

Comment: So now to capture $ID2 for each record, I do:  foreach ($row2 as $result5) {
  $blurb = $row2[0]['ID2'];
}

Comment: Or rather, foreach ($row2 as $result5) {
  $blurb = $result5[0]['ID2'];
}

Comment: Use `$result5['ID2']` because `$result5` points to one of the sub-arrays of `$row2`.  So get the `[0]` out of there.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this one to grab **first 10 records**.

```
//Query code ends here
$results2->execute();
$row2 = $results2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$ccount=0;$data=null;
foreach ($row2 as $result5) {
  $ccount++;
    $data[]=$result5;
    if($ccount>9) {break;}
      }

$blurb = $data;
```

Comment: I will try that. And instead of $data=null, I just change to data=$row2[0]['ID2']; (which is the date I want to pull from each record returned), correct?

Comment: Please try like $data[]=$result5['ID2' ];

Comment: The `$count` is nonsense here. We assume you have already limited the results in your SQL with `LIMIT`. The `$data[]` array append doesn't make sense because `fetchAll()` has already returned all your rows.

Comment: We can not assume  in programming .That's why I have put.he has not mention about limit in sql.So I have written.

Comment: correct, i already limited results previously. Anyway, it worked by doing foreach ($row2 as $result5) { $blurb = $result5['ID2'];}

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Please read above comment and give clearification

Comment: @bhaskarbhatt _"I have a large PDO statement that will return a max of 10 records"_ implies the limit is in SQL, and even if it wasn't already, using a `$count` incrementing var to `break` a loop is not a good suggestion.